# Leaving someone with lots of questions in mind

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am after a single word or maybe couple of words that we usually use to describe the situation when someone leaves us with lots of questions in our mind.

For example (this is not the exact scenario): Someone goes on holidays with some pending tasks they were supposed to complete.

I used this word before as well but can't remember it anymore. I don't think it's *out of the blue*, or *left blank*.

Example sentence:

> I requested them to call x company so that we will be clear on what
>   went wrong when we were requesting an order, but he/she left me
>   _______ and went on holidays.

**Some more context**

I am planning to use it to complain about someone's behaviour as they left me with questions and went on holidays

Comment: You can refer to *unanswered questions* or *outstanding issues*.

Comment: out on a limb, or left me hanging

Comment: Your expanded question doesn't make sense Who are "them"? Who is "he/she" - someone from "them" or someone from "x company".  You can say "she left it outstanding" or "he didn't call them".  Reword the sentence to use an expression you do know.

Comment: It sounds like an *incomplete handover*.

Comment: She left you *stranded* ([definition 2](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stranded)).

Comment: Maybe with the context, would be 'in the dark', or 'out in the cold'. Or maybe, as an ex-girlfriend did to me,  'she dropped me like a wet sock'

Answer (score 4):

**High and dry** — [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/high--and--dry)

> in a deprived or distressing situation; deserted; stranded
>   *"We missed the last bus and were left high and dry."*

*"but he/she left me **high and dry** and went on holidays."*

**On the rocks** — [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/on--the--rocks)

> *Informal.* in or into a state of disaster or ruin
>   *"Their marriage is on the rocks."*

*"but he/she left me **on the rocks** and went on holidays."*

**Stranded** — [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/stranded)

> *(usually used in the passive)* to bring into or leave in a helpless position
>   *"He was stranded in the middle of nowhere."*

*"but he/she left me **stranded** and went on holidays."*

**Desert** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/desert)

> Abandon (a person, cause, or organization) in a way considered disloyal or treacherous
>   *"he deserted his wife and daughter and went back to England"*

*"but he/she **deserted** me and went on holidays."*

Comment: Should I leave them as separate answers?

Comment: I don't think so.  They're all a serviceable word for the OP's question but of the 4 words/expressions, I think that "high and dry" says it best...for me, of course. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you were **left in the lurch.**

> Abandoned in a difficult position without help.

the phrase finder: left in the lurch.